# How should I use highchart's method setData()?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do I use the `setData` method. I assume that I'm using it in a wrong way.

I've set up pie chart:

```
var pieChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'pie-chart',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        }, title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: getLang('name'),
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: []
        }]
    })
```

and I have function which uses `pieChart.series[0].setData(items, true)` to provide new data in next format:

```
[{"className":"className","name":"nameOfDevice","y":(float number percent)}]
//array contains objects
```

and redraw the chart. And it's working if I'm adding new data, and not if I'm change existing data and trying to provide it in the same way i.e. changing them and using `pieChart.series[0].setData(items, true)`

I can't understand how I should use `setData()` to dynamically change existing data

Comment: That is how you use it. Sending **true** as the second parameter is not necessary, as true is the default.  I would check that the data you are sending is in the right format, and check the console for errors. Also: when you say it doesn't work, what do you mean, specifically?

Comment: @jlbriggs I mean that chart doesn't change, and data in it too, obviously. I've checked this with console.log. When I'm sending array other length that already in data, it works, when I'm sending array same length it doesn't

Comment: It's strange. Could you use `setData(items, true, true, false);` ? If this won't help, then try to pass on copy of the `items` instead, for example using jQuery: `setData($.extend([], items));`

Comment: @PawełFus `setData(items, true, true, false);` works, but without animation

Comment: Of course. An animation exists only if you have exactly the same number of points.

Comment: @PawełFus I have. For example, I'm calling `setData([{name: 'first', y: 61}, {name: 'second', y: 39}])` and after that  `setData([{name: 'first', y: 55}, {name: 'second', y: 45}])`

Comment: Just tested, works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/nb2gwa4k/1/